# How do I send a JSON body as part of multipart/form-data with Paw?

Tags: rest, paw-app

I have a REST request that accepts multipart/form-data. This request is already working with an Angular front-end. It expects both an array of files in a parameter called `files[]` and a JSON body in a parameter with the name `body`. In Paw, it seems like I can get the multipart files to be recognized by my endpoint but the body doesn't appear to be the correct content type (`application/json`). Is there any way to specify the content type for each part of a multipart POST in Paw?

Details:

The error message I'm getting on the server-side is:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
```

The config for the body in Paw is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution to this please?

Answer (score 0):

Years have passed and no answer has been posted when I just asked myself the same question.

**Here is the answer for the next ones!:**

To send a json, just use the `{JSON}` annotation to format JSON strings inline.

[image]

This will not only format your JSON, but the correct content-type will be sent during the request.